# "Pay taxes from" vs "Pay taxes for"

Tags: phrases

Below sentence from VOA English, "So we're still paying taxes from that property that was lost a couple years ago from the dune toppling over on top of it.".

I think we should say "paying taxes for that property", not "paying taxes from that property".

In oral English, both are correct or the first one is better?

thanks

Comment: Both are fine.  Using "for" would be less apt to confuse an E2Ler, but "from" is meaningful if one understands the multitude of senses of the word.

Comment: I would say taxes _on_ property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate preposition in this case is "taxes **on** that property" (226K results in Google vs. 900 for "for" and 35 for "from". You would also say that you've obtained and are paying off a mortgage **on** the property or that someone has obtained a lien **on** the property.